# Domain of a non continuous piecewise function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been trying to determine the domain of this piecewise function but I'm not sure how I would write it since its a non continuous piecewise function.

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x+1, & 0<x\le4;\\
5, & 6 \le x <8;\\
7x, & 8\le x \le 11.
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

The domain is

$$(0,4]\cup[6,11]$$

as all the given expressions are defined. Continuity is irrelevant.

Comment: Wouldn't jump discontinuities still be relevant even though all of the functions themselves are continuous?

Comment: @N.Bar: why would they ?

Comment: Not sure I exactly understand what you mean by "continuity is irrelevant" just because all of the functions themselves are continuous. Unless it's piecewise continuous, the piecewise function as a whole won't be continuous (jump discontinuities).

Comment: @N.Bar: where did you see that continuity is to be discussed ?

Comment: It's just your last statement, "Continuity is irrelevant." I'm not sure what you mean by that, but it's definitely not true for all piecewise functions defined by continuous functions (as your answer would insinuate).

Comment: @N.Bar: grrr, I am answering the OP. Please stop confusing matters with this irrelevant topic.